# egg.el is loaded but egg-minor-mode is not enabled (no "C-x v" key bindings)

Tags: git, emacs

All "M-x egg-" commands work ok

```
M-x egg-start-new-branch
   start new branch with name: xxx
```

But all of the "C-x v " key-bindings are still bound to "vc-" commands
(I expected C-x v b to bind to egg-start-new-branch)

```
C-h k
   C-x v b runs the command vc-switch-backend, which is an interactive
```

Do I need to do somethings else besides doing a (require 'egg)?

---

Additional info

"Describe variable: egg-minor-mode"

```
 "egg-minor-mode is a variable defined in `egg.el'. Its value is t"
```

"M-x describe-minor-mode"  ->  egg-minor-mode

```
 "no such minor mode"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late, but I just ran into the same problem.
You mention in a comment that you're using git 1.7. The thing is, egg requires version 1.6 to work, and it actually checks that you're using that version [at line 5939](https://github.com/bogolisk/egg/blob/master/egg.el#L5939). You can see that when the string doesn't match, the body of the `when` form doesn't get executed; but this is precisely where the keymap is set!

So if you wanna be adventurous, you can just replace the `1.6.` by `1.`, or `1.7.` (but then you'll have to remember to change it when you upgrade git to 1.8) and egg-mode will load fine, keymap and all. Use at your own risk, though; I don't know what changes version 1.7 introduced, and egg might do something unexpected.

Comment: Fantastic; indeed, after replacing 1.6 to 1.7 the key bindings work, and probably also opened a can of worms :) Thanks!

Comment: Somebody should report a bug; if the git version is wrong, it should not just die and leave a zombie mode behind.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do `M-x customize-group` for egg and check the value of `egg-mode-key-prefix`? This has to be set to `"C-x v"` for it to work properly; if you changed it anywhere (maybe in your .emacs?) the key bindings will not work properly.

Comment: Does `C-h w egg-start-new-branch` tell you a different binding?

Comment: @philis: I get "egg-start-new-branch is not on any key"

Comment: @tikhon: C-h v (Describe variable) egg-mode-key-prefix returns 'Its value is "C-x v"'

Comment: @jd: The fact that variable `egg-mode-key-prefix` has that value, or any value, says nothing about whether you are in a mode that uses that variable. Are you in `egg-minor-mode` or not when you try to use `C-x v`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `egg`.  Perhaps you have to be in some mode (e.g. `egg-minor-mode`) in order for the key bindings you expect to be active?

If you feel/know you are in the right mode and that mode's key bindings do not seem to include what you expect, you can take a closer look by doing this: Load library [`help-fns+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el), and use <kbd>C-h M-k</kbd> to see the bindings of each keymap you're interested in.   See also [HelpPlus](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HelpPlus).

Another idea is of course to take a look at the egg source code and see what's happening. The Emacs debugger is your friend: `M-x debug-on-entry SOME-FUNCTION`.

IOW, unless someone else here has some specific egg-knowledgable help for you (sorry; I do not), your best bet is to rummage around a bit to find out what's going on.

(Later) Actually, I see now that you mention the mode in the subject line, yourself.  So try this, to load the file and then turn on the minor mode:

```
(require 'egg)
(egg-minor-mode 1)
```

Comment: Drew: (part-1) I tried the following. Made sure that (require 'egg) and (egg-minor-mode 1) are in my .emacs. Also load help-fns+. Restarted emacs and opened a python file that is under git control.  Did a "Describe variable: egg-minor-mode" and get back "egg-minor-mode is a variable defined in `egg.el'. Its value is t".  So far all looks ok. However note that if I do a "C-h m" to list the file's modes, it shows python mode and several minor modes; however egg-minor-mode is NOT one of them.

Comment: Drew: (part-2): Also, if I do a "M-x describe-minor-mode" and I type, for example, auto-complete-mode it describes it; but if I try egg-minor-mode, I get "no such minor mode". So, it seems that the variable egg-minor-mode is "true", but the mode is not really enabled? Using help-fns+, if I do "M-x describe-keymap egg-minor-mode-map, all of the expected keymappings are listed, but those are the ones not enabled, I guess because the egg-minor-mode hasn't kicked-in.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like `(egg-minor-mode 1)` is not the way to turn on the mode, which would mean that it does not follow the normal convention. You will need to look in the source file that defines the mode. But first try `M-x egg-minor-mode`, to turn it on manually. If everything works OK after you do that, then do `C-h f egg-minor-mode` and click the link leading to its definition. Check its doc string and look at the code, to determine how to turn it on using Lisp. (And yes, you cannot always judge by the *variable*'s value whether the mode is on/off.)

Comment: Also, if `egg-minor-mode` is not a global minor mode then you need to be in the same buffer to use it as where you turn it on. If you turn it on in your init file, you need to make sure you turn it on in the buffer you want. `(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "foo") (egg-minor-mode 1))`.

Comment: Did you read the manual, here: <https://github.com/bogolisk/egg/wiki/manual>? It says "_Once activated, egg will turn on egg-minor-mode when a
file was opened in a git repository_. However, the first thing should
be done after loading the first time is to to customize egg."  Did you "activate" egg?  Did you open a file in a git repository?

Comment: My impression from a quick look at the code is that you just need to do `M-x egg-minor-mode` _in the buffer (e.g. file) where you want that mode to be on_. Try it.  Also, apparently you need GIT version 1.6 (or else it does nothing), and then just `C-x C-f` should use `egg-minor-mode`.  See the code just after the definition of `egg-minor-mode-find-file-hook`.

Comment: Drew: first, thanks for all the suggestions. Using git version 1.7.5.4. When I open a python file, in the status bar I see the current Git branch/info. I assume that recognizing the presence of a git repo is because of the vc module, not because of egg, since at this point none of the egg keybindings work. After I do an "M-x egg-minor-mode" (turn-on manually) nothing seems to change (I can still execute all the egg- commands via M-x, but the keys are still bound to the vc- commands as I describe in the original post).

Comment: After you toggle `egg-minor-mode'`that way, are you sure you are in `egg-minor-mode` What is the value of variable `egg-minor-mode` What does `C-h m`say about the minor modes -- is egg among them? This really is the first question you need to find the answer to: are you really in egg minor mode?

Comment: Drew: after toggling egg-minor-mode, while in a buffer that contains a file that is in a git repository, the results are the same as I described above in (part-1) and (part-2). "C-h m" does not list egg as one of the minor modes; however the variable egg-minor-mode is t.

Comment: So it seems you are in `egg-minor-mode`, and `C-h M-k` shows that that mode's keymap has all of the bindings you want, and `C-x v` is the actual prefix of those keys and the value of `egg-mode-key-prefix`, but none of those keys work and `C-h k` shows that they are bound to regular VC commands.  At this point I'd say either try to debug the code, using `M-x debug-on-entry` or by adding `(debug)` calls to it, or try to contact the library author.  Between what Mattias has done to try to repro it and what you've found out from Emacs itself, I'd say it's time to ask the author.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used egg-mode before, but to debug I tried this. I installed egg.el by checking out the git repository.

```
git clone git://github.com/byplayer/egg.git
```

After that I started emacs, issued `M-x load-file` and gave the path `t/egg/egg.el` and it loaded successfully. After that I opened a file in that folder `C-x C-f` followed by `t/egg/egg.el`. Immediatelly the file loaded, Emacs automatically entered Major Mode Emacs-Lisp and minor-mode egg. And `C-x v` directly shows me: `Egg:file:` in the status bar. So everything seems to work perfectly out of the box.

When you open a file to automatically test egg-minor-mode, are you sure that you open a file that is checked in with git, where you have a .git folder in the folder/path?

Unless knowing more about your .emacs and setup I can't debug further, but I am not able to reproduce your error as it is.

Comment: Mattias: It's a python project which I cloned from github. All git commands work from the command shell, and when I open a python file, in the status bar of the emacs buffer I see the current Git branch/info. I don't get any errors when starting emacs (no error message requesting to start w/ --debug-info), and all the egg- commands work ok via M-x egg-... (so, the load command in my .emacs file seems to be working?). It's just that the keybindings don't work.